# Golang joy4 package publish example does not work

Tags: go, rtmp, flv

- Server: https://github.com/nareix/joy4/tree/master/examples/http_flv_and_rtmp_server
- Publish: https://github.com/nareix/joy4/tree/master/examples/rtmp_publish

I started the server first, then ran `rtmp_publish` to publish flv data to the server. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

After that, I tried to publish with ffmpeg:

```
$ ffmpeg -re -i projectindex.flv -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1936/app/publish
```

It worked and I could play the stream with VLC.

Then I checked the log on the server. For ffmpeg, the log contains `Accept` and `Parsing URL`. But for `rtmp_publish.go`, the log only contains `Accept`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with a flv file (`sample-3.flv`) downloaded from https://getsamplefiles.com/sample-video-files/flv, and both ffmpeg and `rtmp_publish/main.go` work. Can you please test with this file?

If it works, then it's most likely that the flv file you tested at first contains stream that is not supported by the package.

I haved checked the information of `sample-3.flv` with `ffprobe`:

```
$ ffprobe sample-3.flv
Input #0, flv, from 'sample-3.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
  Duration: 00:00:30.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7836 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn
```

You can check yours and compare the output with the one above (but I don't know what is or is not supported by the package).

---

**Notes for others who want to run the example**:

First, the source code of the package does not contain a `go.mod` file. Create one at the root of the repository:

```
$ go mod init github.com/nareix/joy4
```

`http_flv_and_rtmp_server` listens on port `1935` by default. So if we don't change the server, we have to change `rtmp_publish/main.go`:

```
- file, _ := avutil.Open("projectindex.flv")
- conn, _ := rtmp.Dial("rtmp://localhost:1936/app/publish")
+ file, _ := avutil.Open("sample-3.flv")
+ conn, _ := rtmp.Dial("rtmp://localhost:1935/app/publish")
```

And the ffmpeg command should be:

```
$ ffmpeg -re -i sample-3.flv -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/app/publish
```

And the stream can be played with `ffplay`:

```
$ ffplay http://localhost:8089/app/publish
```

Make sure `sample-3.flv` is in the current working directory when running `ffmpeg` or `go run rtmp_publish/main.go`

Comment: Thank you for answering, Yes, you are right.
But I means that After Server On, when i command  ffmpeg -re -i sample-3.flv -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/app/publish. I can play the flv video using VLC Player with network stream. ffmpeg published flv data.
but if I use rtmp_publish/main.go, it is not working like  ffmpeg cmd. different from repo's owner comments "// as same as: ffmpeg -re -i projectindex.flv -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1936/app/publish"
After executing rtmp_publish/main.go , I Can not play the flv video with VLC Player network stream.

Comment: Just confirmed, I can play it in VLC player. The url I input into VLC player is: `http://localhost:8089/app/publish`.

Comment: Thank u for answering, It works very well.
I think that before using sample-3.flv file my file is originally mp4 file and i rename flv file. this is reason of not working. Thank you very much.